# How should I approach having multiple tabs on my drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a website that has a drop down menu. Right now, it only has support for one tab of the drop down menu (only one thing that can be clicked on and dropped down). What I want to do is have multiple of these tabs going across the page on the same line as the tab that is already on the page.

I'm wondering how I should approach adding another tab to this drop down menu. I've tried multiple things to get multiple tabs on the drop down menu, but they haven't worked. What would I need to do to have more tabs, like the tab I already have, in my drop down menu? How should I approach it and what things what I need to copy, paste, modify, or add from my existing drop down menu with one tab?

Here is my JSFiddle with my drop down menu: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leoalfredmusic/7y6Rf/)

Basically I want to add more tabs (things that I can drop down) to my drop down menu, going across the page in the same line as the tab I have already made. I have tried copying and pasting another tab in just the HTML code, but because they shared the same class, the jQuery code activated both tabs when one was clicked. How would I add more tabs while having each tab be processed separately with jQuery, so that both tabs wouldn't activate at the same time, and so that the tabs would go across the page, on the same line as the tab I've already made?

This is my basic html:

```
<h1 id="name">LFX Music</h1>
<div class="click-nav-login">
<ul class="no-js-login">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="clicker-login">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Privacy</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Sign out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script src="scripts/js/navigation.js"></script>
```

But a problem comes in where if I have another tab, if one tab is activated, they all get activated because they all have the same class and are processed with this same jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
$('.click-nav-login > ul').toggleClass('no-js-login js-login');
$('.click-nav-login .js-login ul').hide();
$('.click-nav-login .js-login').click(function(e) {
    $('.click-nav-login .js-login ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker-login').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.click-nav-login .js-login ul').is(':visible')) {
        $('.click-nav-login .js-login ul', this).slideUp();
        $('.clicker-login').removeClass('active');
    }
});
});
```

How can I fix this issue and have more tabs in my drop down menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a diferent id with the class.
and you pass the element to click, i have this code in mi site:

```
      function acordion(elemenid) {
        var element = $("#" + elemenid);
        if (element.hasClass("active")) {
            element.removeClass("active");
            element.children().first().next().slideToggle("fast");
            element.children().children().children().attr('src','http://example.com/site/images/up-dpwn.jpg')

        } else {
            element.css('min-height', '0px');
            element.addClass("active");
            element.children().first().next().slideToggle("fast");
            element.children().children().children().attr('src','http://example.com/site/images/down.jpg');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please put this in the jsfiddle so that I can see what stuff I need to change and how it works?